# how to lower frequency of a sound file in matlab?

Tags: matlab, audio

I am new to programming and sound processing,
I have been using matlab to process sound files, a few of which are ultrasonic.
my sampling rate is 250kHz.
I Would like to be able to play the sounds at an audible frequency, there for i need to lower the pitch of the sounds without changing the speed.
The frequency in the sound files are around 70 kHz, and i need to lower them to about 20 kHz (human hearing range 20 Hz - 20 kHz), about 4 times lower.
If i simply change the sampling rate to 250000*4, i get the right frequency but the file become shorter/faster.

I have tried a few things:

1. Delete every 4th bin of the original vector and multiplying sampling rate by 4. it did the opposite of what i intended and also changed the length.
2. Duplicate every bin the the audio 4 times and keep the sampling rate, it actually lowered the frequency and the length did not change, but the frequencies were mirrored it 4 times
3. A method i found online,which i don't understand, this method gave the best result: lower frequency and same file length but it changed the structure of the sound file (see link to spectrogram)

here is the code sample of the last method:

function [signal]=lower_the_freq(original)
% original = rawClip.values';
    binlen=length(original);
    sfq=250000;
    duration=binlen/sfq;

% plot original signal
     subplot(211);

```
 fourierTransform = fft(original);
 spectrogram(original,1024,512,1024,sfq,'yaxis');    %run the spectrogram
 title('Original signal')
```

% downsample spectrum by a factor of 2
     n = 2; % downsampling factor
     newSpectrum = fourierTransform(1:n:end);

% zero-pad the positive and negative ends of the spectrum
    pad = floor(length(fourierTransform)/4);
    fourierTransform = [zeros(1,pad) fftshift(newSpectrum) zeros(1,pad)];

% inverse transform
     signal = ifft(length(original)*fftshift(fourierTransform),'symmetric');

% plot the downshifted signal
     subplot(212)
     spectrogram(signal,1024,512,1024,sfq,'yaxis');    %run the spectrogram
     title('Shifted signal')

image

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iPB3JYMTma4L6DsmhwZgjRjQFLo2Avz8/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

In the end, i took the advice of @chipaudette
in his answer to a similar question
[link to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27213618/advice-on-converting-ultrasonic-rat-call-signal-into-human-audible-range-with-ma)
and i used Audacity to lower frequency, worked like a charm. in case anyone want's to see the final product, i add a link.
[link to manual](https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/change_pitch.html)
[link to final product](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1897X9pEAruhAFy3AI_EhrvbOsooq1zkv/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, changing the sample rate also changes audio speed. Then apply a time-scale modification algorithm such as WSOLA or Phase-Vocoder and you'll get a pitch shifted audio file with the same length (speed).

Check this article: [A Review of Time-Scale Modification of Music Signals](https://www.mdpi.com/2076-3417/6/2/57)